# Logging request/response in Nest.js

Tags: typescript, nestjs

New to Nest.js,
I am trying to implement a simple logger for tracing HTTP requests like :

```
:method :url :status :res[content-length] - :response-time ms
```

From my understanding the best place for that would be [interceptors](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors). But I Also use [Guards](https://docs.nestjs.com/guards) and as mentionned, Guards are triggered **after** middlewares but **before** interceptors.

Meaning, my forrbidden accesses are not logged. I could write the logging part in two different places but rather not. Any idea?

Thanks!

My Interceptor code:

```
import { Injectable, NestInterceptor, ExecutionContext, HttpException, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class HTTPLoggingInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, call$: Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
    const now = Date.now();
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

    const method = request.method;
    const url = request.originalUrl;

    return call$.pipe(
      tap(() => {
        const response = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();
        const delay = Date.now() - now;
        console.log(`${response.statusCode} | [${method}] ${url} - ${delay}ms`);
      }),
      catchError((error) => {
        const response = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();
        const delay = Date.now() - now;
        console.error(`${response.statusCode} | [${method}] ${url} - ${delay}ms`);
        return throwError(error);
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58970970/nestjs-log-response-data-object

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I ended up injecting a classic logger on the raw app.
This solution is not the best since it is not integrated to the Nest flow but works well for standard logging needs.

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { FastifyAdapter, NestFastifyApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';
import { ApplicationModule } from './app.module';
import * as morgan from 'morgan';

async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(ApplicationModule, new FastifyAdapter());
    app.use(morgan('tiny'));

    await app.listen(process.env.PORT, '0.0.0.0');
}

if (isNaN(parseInt(process.env.PORT))) {
    console.error('No port provided. ');
    process.exit(666);
}

bootstrap().then(() => console.log('Service listening : ', process.env.PORT));
```

Comment: You can implement a class-based `middleware`, so that you can take advantage of Nestjs `dependency injection`. And even `morgan` uses some hack to record the request and response. So we can just implement our `middleware` similarly.

Answer (score 50):

https://github.com/julien-sarazin/nest-playground/issues/1#issuecomment-682588094

You can use middleware for that.

```
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

@Injectable()
export class AppLoggerMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  private logger = new Logger('HTTP');

  use(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction): void {
    const { ip, method, path: url } = request;
    const userAgent = request.get('user-agent') || '';

    response.on('close', () => {
      const { statusCode } = response;
      const contentLength = response.get('content-length');

      this.logger.log(
        `${method} ${url} ${statusCode} ${contentLength} - ${userAgent} ${ip}`
      );
    });

    next();
  }
}
```

and in the AppModule

```
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer): void {
    consumer.apply(AppLoggerMiddleware).forRoutes('*');
  }
}
```

Comment: But close callback is never called

Comment: Response data is missing from response object ?

Comment: how can add response body in log

Comment: To log the body, add ``Request Body: ${JSON.stringify(request.body)}``

Comment: What about fastify

Comment: @HafizTemuri, it won't log the response body, it logs request's body.

Comment: Yes, you probably won't need to log the response body. Most likely you want to log the request body, so you can reproduce the request later.

Answer (score 16):

How about use `finish` event instead of `close` event.

```js
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware, Logger } from "@nestjs/common";

@Injectable()
export class LoggerMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  private logger = new Logger("HTTP");

  use(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction): void {
    const { ip, method, originalUrl } = request;
    const userAgent = request.get("user-agent") || "";

    response.on("finish", () => {
      const { statusCode } = response;
      const contentLength = response.get("content-length");

      this.logger.log(
        `${method} ${originalUrl} ${statusCode} ${contentLength} - ${userAgent} ${ip}`,
      );
    });

    next();
  }
}
```

Because as far as know `express` connection is maintained after send response.
So `close` event can't be fired

### Reference

[01. Node document about `response` event](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/http.html#http_event_close_1).
[02. Github issue](https://github.com/julien-sarazin/nest-playground/issues/1)

Comment: How to get data that sent to user in response object in that middleware? @Stark Joen

Comment: Well actually I guess you can look into `response` side

Comment: I dont find data in Response object?Could you please check that ?@Stark

Answer (score 5):

I decided to use Morgan as middleware to intercept the requests since I like the formatting options, whilst using the standard Nest Logger to handle the output to retain consistency with the rest of my app.

```
// middleware/request-logging.ts
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import morgan, { format } from 'morgan';

export function useRequestLogging(app) {
    const logger = new Logger('Request');
    app.use(
        morgan('tiny', {
            stream: {
                write: (message) => logger.log(message.replace('\n', '')),
            },
        }),
    );
}
```

```
// main.ts
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { useRequestLogging } from './middleware/request-logging';

async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    useRequestLogging(app);
    await app.listen(configService.get<number>('SERVER_PORT'));
    logger.log(`Application is running on: ${await app.getUrl()}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code =>

```
@Injectable()
export class LoggerMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
    use(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {
        const { ip, method, originalUrl: url  } = req;
        const hostname = require('os').hostname();
        const userAgent = req.get('user-agent') || '';
        const referer = req.get('referer') || '';

        res.on('close', () => {
            const { statusCode, statusMessage } = res;
            const contentLength = res.get('content-length');
            logger.log(`[${hostname}] "${method} ${url}" ${statusCode} ${statusMessage} ${contentLength} "${referer}" "${userAgent}" "${ip}"`);
        });

        next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### app.interceptor.ts

```
// Import required modules
import { Injectable, NestInterceptor, ExecutionContext, CallHandler, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class ReqLoggingInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  private readonly logger = new Logger('HTTP_REQUEST');

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    // Extract request and response objects
    const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const res = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();

    // Record current timestamp
    const now = Date.now();

    // Determine if in production
    const isProduction = process.env.DB_HOST?.toLowerCase()?.includes('stage') || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'local';

    // Construct log message
    const logMessage =
      `METHOD - ${req.method} | URL - ${req.url} | ` +
      (!isProduction
        ? ''
        : `QUERY - ${JSON.stringify(req.query)} | PARAMS - ${JSON.stringify(req.params)} | BODY - ${JSON.stringify(req.body)} `) +
      `${this.getColorizedStatusCode(res.statusCode)} ${Date.now() - now} ms`;

    // Handle the observable
    return next.handle().pipe(
      tap(() => {
        // Log request details on success
       req.url && this.logger.log(logMessage);
      }),
      catchError((error) => {
        // Log request details on error and rethrow the error
      req.url && this.logger.log(logMessage);
        throw error;
      }),
    );
  }

  private getColorizedStatusCode(statusCode: number): string {
    // ANSI escape codes for colorization
    const yellow = '\x1b[33m';
    const reset = '\x1b[0m';

    return `${yellow}${statusCode}${reset}`;
  }
}
```

I'm using above logging interceptor instead of morgan or others...
Last step is to configure above interceptor in app.module.ts.

**Note:**

1. I'm logging request body, query, params as for debugging errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with logging the correct status code due to the filters running after the interceptor.  The only solution I could come to that I was comfortable with was to implement the logging in the interceptor.  Very similar to how you have done so in your code.  While the filter runs after the interceptor runs the observable can be leveraged to execute a function after it completes successfully or errors.

The trick for me was that the statuscode on the response is not guaranteed to be set properly even in the *tap* or the *catchError* operators.  I solved this by checking the method of the request and if it's a POST method then I know the successful response is a 201 else it is always a 200.
If I receive an error I grab the status code from the error and use that instead of the status code on the response object.  Since my Exception filter will run before the observable completes I know that a statusCode will exist on my error object at this time.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I am not sure this is a way i am confortable with. In my service definition many actions are done through POST request but half of them reply with a 204 since no data needs to be returned. Moreover I do not understand why a "workaround" solution is needed for such basic need. I mean i have been a heavy user of nodeJS since a while, used tons of frameworks (express, Hapi, Loopback, Sails) I have even developed my own.. Seeing how well design Nest is I am absolutely sure we are missing something. I will post back as soon as i find a solution.

Comment: I was not really comfortable with this either.  I agree it seems like it's something that you can do in frameworks like express very easily.  The other option I found that worked was to put a wrap the logic that is actually logging the request in a setTimeout and a time of 0.  This seemed to allow the status code from my filter to be set properly and I didn't have to assume the status code.  However I thought this solution was even less ideal then assuming a 201 vs 200.  If you find a more ideal solution please do post it back.

Answer (score 0):

**merge(fromEvent())**

```
import { NestMiddleware, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { FastifyRequest, FastifyReply } from 'fastify';
import { InjectPinoLogger, PinoLogger } from 'nestjs-pino';
import serializers from 'pino-std-serializers';
import { merge, fromEvent, first } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable()
export class LoggerMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  constructor(
    @InjectPinoLogger(LoggerMiddleware.name)
    private readonly logger: PinoLogger,
  ) {}

  use(req: FastifyRequest, res: FastifyReply['raw'], next: (error?: Error) => void) {
    const method = req.method;
    const url = req.url;
    const now = Date.now();
    const traceId = this.cls.get<IAsyncStorage>(TRACE_ID);

    this.logger.assign({ traceIdContext: traceId.value });

    this.logger.debug({
      info: {
        url,
        now,
        method,
        country,
        request: serializers.req(req),
        requestType: 'external-request',
      },
    });

    const loggerData = {
      info: {
        url,
        method,
        country,
        response: serializers.res(res),
        requestType: 'response-from',
        data: '<omited>', // JSON.stringify(this.responseJson),
      },
    };

    const event$ = merge(fromEvent(res, 'finish'), fromEvent(res, 'close'));
    const eventError$ = merge(fromEvent(res, 'error'));

    event$.pipe(first()).subscribe({
      next: () => {
        this.logger.debug(loggerData);
      },
    });

    eventError$.pipe(first()).subscribe({
      next: () => {
        this.logger.error(loggerData);
      },
    });

    return next();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

You can follow the [LoggerMiddleware](https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware) provided in the official documentation to implement your custom logger.

You can apply the logger to wildcard * route, to log all requests and responses. And inside the logger class, you can pick custom fields to log, before and after the request:

> ```
> export class AppModule implements NestModule {
>   configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
>     consumer
>       .apply(LoggerMiddleware)
>       .forRoutes('*');
>   }
> }
>
> class LoggerMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
>   use(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {
>     console.log('Request', req.method, req.originalUrl, /*...*/);
>     next();
>     console.log('Response', res.statusCode, res.statusMessage, /*...*/);
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: res.statusCode is always 200 and res.finised is always false.