# Nestjs log response data object

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, nestjs

I want to log the incoming requests and outgoing responses in NestJs. I took information from here [Logging request/response in Nest.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55093055/logging-request-response-in-nest-js) and from the docs [NestJs Aspect Interception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zlv2g.png).

It would be awesome to achieve this by not using external packages, so I would highly prefer a native "Nest" solution.

For the request logging I currently use this code

```
@Injectable()
export class RequestInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  private logger: Logger = new Logger(RequestInterceptor.name);

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const {
      originalUrl,
      method,
      params,
      query,
      body,
    } = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

    this.logger.log({
      originalUrl,
      method,
      params,
      query,
      body,
    });

    return next.handle();
  }
}
```

This would log the following result for `GET /users`

[image]

I also want to log the outgoing response. Currently I use this interceptor

```
@Injectable()
export class ResponseInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  private logger: Logger = new Logger(ResponseInterceptor.name);

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const { statusCode } = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();

    return next.handle().pipe(
      tap(() =>
        this.logger.log({
          statusCode,
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This would log the following result for `GET /users`

[image]

but how can I access the data that was sent back to the client?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, I would suggest combining these into one logger, just so all the logging logic is in one place.

Second, to get the data being sent back to the client, in your `tap` function you need to add a parameter to the function, usually we call it data, so you can know what is being sent back. This is a little obscured by the Nest, as what the observable is working on is not really clear, but in the end, something like this ends up working for you:

```js
@Injectable()
export class AspectLogger implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler) {
    const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const { statusCode } = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();
    const { originalUrl, method, params, query, body } = req;

    console.log({
      originalUrl,
      method,
      params,
      query,
      body,
    });

    return next.handle().pipe(
      tap((data) =>
        console.log({
          statusCode,
          data,
        })
      )
    );
  }
}
```

This will also work if you decide to break it back into it's two separate interceptors, but having a single one can make it easier to determine call time as well.

Comment: as formatted the response body logger didn't work for me, I had to write it as `return next.handle().pipe(tap(data => console.log({ statusCode, data })));` in case anyone else has a linter that is fighting them