# Nestjs interceptors are not called when apollo-fedaration resolves a field

Tags: graphql, nestjs, apollo-server

I'm trying to create a logging interceptor with graphql, apollo federation and nestjs. I'm following [this guide](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors) and modified my code to

```
import {
  Injectable, NestInterceptor, ExecutionContext, CallHandler,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class LoggingInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  public intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    console.log('Before...');

    const now = Date.now();
    return next
      .handle()
      .pipe(
        tap(() => console.log(`After... ${Date.now() - now}ms`)),
      );
  }
}
```

And apply it like this:

```
const app: INestApplication = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, new ExpressAdapter(expressApp), {
    logger,
  });
app.useGlobalInterceptors(new LoggingInterceptor());
```

In tcpdump an http request is present between apollo-federation and this service when I post graphql request to federation. Despite it there're no logs from my interceptor. But If i make a direct graphql request to this ms (w/o federation), logs are there.

Also another question, I would like to catch response headers and string body. I think this could be done on express level only, but it somehow doesn't work at all, I tried everything in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55093055/logging-request-response-in-nest-js).

Answer (score 3):

In order to make interceptors work on federated field resolvers you need to enable them when configuring `GraphQLFederationModule` using `fieldResolverEnhancers` property:

```
GraphQLFederationModule.forRoot({
  ...
  fieldResolverEnhancers: ['interceptors'],
}),
```

Comment: Insane - thank you so much for posting this answer, was really banging my head against the wall.