# how to setup morgan-boddy in nestjs

Tags: node.js, logging, nestjs

I want to setup [morgan-boddy](https://github.com/sirrodgepodge/morgan-body) as a midldleware to log requests and responses.

So I've created a function like that:

```
export function RequestLogging(app) {
  const logger = new Logger('Request');
  app.use(
    morganBody(app, {
      stream: { // <--- error is here "Void function return value is used "
        write: (message) => logger.log(message.replace('\n', '')),
      },
    }),
  );
}
```

That I call on main.ts

```
// main.ts

async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    useRequestLogging(app);
    // ...
}
```

However it seems does not work. I've got an error `'Void function return value is used'` on line `stream: {`

Any idea how to fix?

UPDATE:

I tried to go different path and actually just stick morganBody in to main.ts as per docs:

```
  import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
  import morganBody from 'morgan-body';

  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  // hook morganBody to express app
  morganBody(app); <-- getting error here "TS2345: Argument of type 'INestApplication' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Application'."
```

I wish there was a proper documentation how to approach in nestjs.

Comment: What about this doesn't work? Do you just not get the logs? Do you errors in your application? "Does not work" doesn't tell us much and makes debugging and figuring out the issue more difficult

Comment: @JayMcDoniel added error details

Comment: what if you do `write: (message) => { this.logger.log(message.replace('\n'. '')); }`?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel does not work this way either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty interesting middleware. It ends up needing the express instance itself because it calls `app.use(morgan)` and `app.response.send()` under the hood. I would really look into some other solution instead of something that accesses the response in this way.

Either way: this set up works

```js
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import * as morgan from 'morgan-body';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const logger = app.get(Logger);
  (morgan as any)(app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance(), {
    stream: {
      write: (message: string) => {
        logger.log(message.replace('\n', ''));
        return true;
      },
    },
  });
  await app.listen(3033);
}
bootstrap();
```

The types for the package are wrong as well, it's not a default export, but a named one, so `import morgan from 'morgan-body'` doesn't work as advertised (at least it didn't for me).

The `return true` is necessary because `write` expects a `stream.writable()` method, which has returns a boolean. You can just default this to true. Then you have to use `app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance()` so that you ensure you pass the express instance to the middleware. Again, wonky setup, but it works.

Comment: Nope. Nest attaches body-parser already, for both JSON and urlencoded

Comment: You mention that you would look into some other solution because `morgan-body` accecing the response in a way, why is it so, Is there anything else you can recommend? May be there is a nestjs native http logger similar to this one that I missed? I didn't manage to find a better one. There is other one called `morgan` but it is a bit limited as it is does not log the body. Here is how it it's integrates with nestjs ref https://stackoverflow.com/a/65406470/415078, seems to me it has similar problem as relying on `express app`

Comment: At least with `morgan` you're applying the middleware directly. Generally, I would not log the body of HTTP requests, as it could mean logging passwords and other secure information, meaning your logs now need to be encrypted and only certain people can be "trusted" with them. I'm the author of [ogma](https://github.com/jmcdo29/ogma) which has an interceptor that does logging for HTTP, GQL, WS, and RPC requests with minimal configuration, so that's what I use.

Comment: Yeah I c, what you mean. However I noticed there is a feature within `morgan-body` that can help with hiding the critical info ref: https://github.com/sirrodgepodge/morgan-body/pull/27. Anyway thanks for help.

Comment: Just tried ogma, it works well, however I wonder if it is possible to log body ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68920628/how-to-unify-nestjs-decorators

Comment: how do i pass options to the morgan with this?

Comment: @olawalejuwonm what do you mean?

Comment: i want to pass options like this morgan({logHeaders:false}) how do i achieve that?

Comment: With regular morgan? `app.use(morgan({ logHeaders: false }))`