# How to unify nestjs decorators

Tags: nestjs

I have two decorators:

```
export const PlainBodyDecode = createParamDecorator(
  async (_, context: ExecutionContext) => {
    const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    if (!req.readable) {
      throw new BadRequestException('Invalid body');
    }

    const body = (await rawBody(req)).toString('utf8').trim();
    return decode(body);
  },
);

export const PlainBody = createParamDecorator(
  async (_, context: ExecutionContext) => {
    const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    if (!req.readable) {
      throw new BadRequestException('Invalid body');
    }

    return (await rawBody(req)).toString('utf8').trim();
  },
```

);

As you can see they are pretty similar.

I really would like to be able to do something like that:

```
export const PlainBodyDecode = createParamDecorator(
 decode(PlainBody());
);
```

If you see what I mean.

Here how I am using the decorator:

```
  @Post('decode')
  decode(@PlainBodyDecode() data: any): string {
    //...
  }
```

Do you have any ideas?

update:

I think I need to do something like:

```
  export const PlainBodyDecode = (decodeBody = true): ParameterDecorator => {
  return createParamDecorator(async (_, context: ExecutionContext) => {
    //...
    if (decodeBody) {
      return decode(body);
    } else {
      return body;
    }
  });
};
```

However it seems does not work

Comment: Why woul you want to do that? if  both are similar then what is the point having them ? 
Can you elaborate more on your use case and how you intend to use these decorators via controller ?

Comment: @Sohan yes, exactly that is why I am looking what is the best way to unify them. Just added the controller code.

Comment: @Sohan I think the param would help, but I am not sure about the right syntax

Comment: I have given one example, see if that can help

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample of using the Custom Parameter deocrator:

You can add you own custom logic inside the decorater

```
    export const RequestHeader = createParamDecorator(
    async (value: any, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
        // extract headers
        const headers = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest().headers;
        // Convert headers to DTO object
        const dto = plainToClass(value, headers, {excludeExtraneousValues: true});
        const errors: ValidationError[] = await validate(dto);

        if (errors.length > 0) {
            //Get the errors and push to custom array
            let validationErrors = errors.map(obj => Object.values(obj.constraints));
            throw new HttpException(`Request Header Validation failed with following Errors: ${validationErrors}`, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        // return header dto object
        return dto;
    }
);

//Using in controller:
 @Post('my-details')
    async myData(
      @Req() req,
      @Res() res,
      @Body() body: myBody,
      @RequestHeader(MyHeaderDto) myHeader: MyHeaderDto,
  ):Promise<MyCustomDataDto> {
```

Note: I have used Typescript here.

Comment: I wonder why the code with explicit ParameterDecorator didn't work? otherwise using createParamDecorator the parameter does not have a proper type.

Comment: As i mentioned I used here TS, so you do not need to type the objects, sometimes the auto typing works for you. Did you tried this ?