# Unable to get request body via NestJS Middleware having application with FastifyAdapter

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, nestjs-fastify

I am working with the NestJS project, and want to log each and every request. I am using [Fastify](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/performance) in my REST API. I made a nest middleware for getting request body:

```
import { HttpException, Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

@Injectable()
export class LoggerMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
        use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
                const { httpVersion, headers, method, baseUrl, params, query, body } = req;
                // body is Undefined!
                console.log('Request Body...', body);                
                next();
        }
}
```

When I print a log into the console, I got the output **undefined**.

**app.module.ts:**

```
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(LoggerMiddleware)
      .forRoutes('*');
  }
}
```

**main.ts:**

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import {
  FastifyAdapter,
  NestFastifyApplication,
} from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter()
  );
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap()
```

Comment: Did you add your `middleware` after `bodyparser` middleware? maybe `bodyparser` middleware run after your middleware then you got `undefined` body. you need `bodyparser` before your middleware

Comment: @AminTaghikhani I didn't use any bodyparser middleware. Should I have to use bodyparse middleware to achieve my task?

Comment: maybe `bodyparser` can help you, because you need to parse payload then get the `body`

Comment: Plenty of answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55093055/logging-request-response-in-nest-js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logging request/response in Nest.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55093055/logging-request-response-in-nest-js)